# Where can I download the latest Windows 7 installation DVD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, iso-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)

I need to do an in-place upgrade to repair my installation of Windows 7 Professional 32-bit but I want to make the process as painless as possible. Is there a place to download the *latest* version of the installation DVD?

Searching Google led me to this link:

> http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-24280.iso

Apparently this is officially hosted by Microsoft but:

1. I can't be sure if it is legitimate
2. I don't know if this is the latest or if there may even be a newer one.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digital River is the digital retail channel for Microsoft software and is legitimate.

As for whether it's the latest version, if it contains SP1, then it is the latest.

<strike>Since you provided no contextual page with that link, I'm hesitant to download the whole ISO just to extract it to find out.</strike>

EDIT: Per the URL provided in the comment, it appears to be the latest version because it includes Service Pack 1.

Comment: Sorry, here is where I got the link from: http://techdows.com/2011/07/download-windows-7-integrated-with-sp1-iso-official-direct-download-links.html

Comment: According to that URL, it's a Service Pack 1 ISO, so in my opinion it is the latest version you're going to find.

Comment: Is there any official statement from Microsoft about digitalrivercontent.net? Its strange that I can't find much information about it.

Comment: It appears Microsoft no longer uses Digital River for a number of their products, but if you go to http://windows7.digitalriver.com you'll see references to the Academic software.

Comment: I can't be sure if it's the latest version or not because I have seen X17-5####.iso and assuming those numbers have anything to do with the version number I assume it's newer if it's higher.

Comment: Here is one of the potentially newer ones I mentioned previously: http://www.wincert.net/forum/index.php?/topic/8906-windows-7-sp1-disk/

Comment: Why not download the one you think is the latest and see if it works? At the moment we're just speculating.

Comment: I also found this here: http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/14-windows-7-direct-download-links 
Looks like it is the latest version. I'm going to download it now. How do I make sure it's legit and uncorrupted after it's done downloading?

Comment: Digital River is a legit reseller.  I can vouch for them as I've purchased software from them in the past.